# Проблема инсталляции VMWare 8 на Win Web Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, vmware

Начну с того, что на Win 7 x64 машинка и её тулзы ставится идеально и все ровно.Но вот на Сервере 2008 возникла проблема с установкой tools-windows. Все устанавливается с полными правами администратора, UAC'ов никаких нет, ограничений тоже.

Во время установки вылезает неприятное окно:

> `The MSI 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\vmware_1316160996\tools-windows.msi' failed.`

Самого .msi я там не нашел нигде, есть только tools-windows-8.8.0.exe, который и выдает описанное выше.Он еще и генерирует лог в папке Temp\2, самое интересное в следующем:

> `This installation is forbidden by system policy. Contact your system administrator.C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\vmware_1316160468\tools-windows.msi`

Долго гуглил, сделал следующее:

- В `Local Security Policy` добавил `Software Restriction Policies` с параметром "`All users except local administrators`".
- Там-же добавил дефолтные правила в `Application Control Policies\App Locker\Windows Installer Rules` таким образом, что все "`Windows Installer`'ы" может запускать любой (`Everyone`), добавил и еще несколько путей для разрешения.

Результат к сожалению - нулевой, ничего не помогает и гугл уже весь выжал в сухую.Помогите советом, пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 1):

Во время установки у меня почему-то не работал tools-windows-8.8.0 (размер файла 51894312 байт) и не  установился windows.iso в папке VMware Workstation.выходило вот такое сообщение

> `The MSI 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\vmware_1316160996\tools-windows.msi' failed.`

У меня системе установлено семерка ултимейт со всеми обновлениями, каспер 2011 базы последние. После этого я взял из temp папки (во время повторной установки VMware Workstation 8.0.0.471780.ехе) установщик tools-windows-8.8.0 и запустил в среде виртуальной машине ХР и там в каталоге `Program Files\VMware\VMware Workstation` я нашел файл windows.iso (размер 61800448байт) выложил для полезной информации из своей практики.